# Add 2nd section under existing section with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

My goal is create another section under the existing section but I have a hard time adding it because of the error that said `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild'` of undefined.

I got an error with the following code:

```
getElementsByClassName("row").appendChild(sectionElement);
```

with this created function:

```
function getElementsByClassName(cl) {
    if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
        document.getElementsByClassName = function (className) {
            var node = [];
            var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
            for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
                if((' ' + elem[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cl + ' ') > -1) retnode.push(elem[i]);
             }
             return node;
        }; 
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class='row'>
    <section class='well well-small'>
        <legend>Select An Animal</legend>
        <form method="post" id="speciesForm">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="btn" >
            <input type="button" class="btn" v>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function will always return `undefined` because if the  `getElementsByClassName` function is not defined, you create it but never call it. If it is defined your function doesn't do anything. A function with no explicit `return` statement will return `undefined`. These modifications to your function should resolve the issue:

```
function getElementsByClassName(cl) {
    if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
        document.getElementsByClassName = function (className) {
           var node = [];
           var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
           for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
             if((' ' + elem[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') > -1) retnode.push(elem[i]);
           }
           return node;
        }; 
        return document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
    } else {
        return document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
    }
}
```

It should also be noted that calling `appendChild` on the result from this function will fail since you are returning an array in your custom function, and the native `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList.

Comment: Could you explain little more? I believed I called the function. Although, I overlooked my code and replace "className" with cl. @Default

Comment: Thank you @Default. Now it get rid of that error. The error is now Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'appendChild'

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return a `NodeList`, which can contain multiple nodes. If you only need to append the `sectionElement` to the first node, try `getElementsByClassName("row")[0].appendChild(sectionElement);`